# how to removed a single value when click the remove options?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

its submit the values

```
// Slider Image

echo '<input style="width:100%" type="hidden" id="all_img" name="all_img" value="' . $all_img .'" />';
```

delete options delete

```
$s_img = explode(',', $single_img);

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $s_img ); $i++ ) {
    echo '<li id="delete_img"><div class="delete"><div alt="f158" class="dashicons dashicons-no" style="display: inline-block;"></div></div>';
    echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url( $s_img[$i], 'full', false ).'" alt="slider image"/><li>';
}
```

delete image Delete Image javascript document body and one click remove id

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.sarea .delete', function() {
    $('#single_img').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using the same `id="delete_img"` for all your images in your `for` loop:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $s_img ); $i++ ) {
    echo '<li id="delete_img"><div class="delete"><div alt="f158" class="dashicons dashicons-no" style="display: inline-block;"></div></div>';
    echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url( $s_img[$i], 'full', false ).'" alt="slider image"/><li>';
}

// delete image
$('#single_img').remove();
```

Since you are using jQuery, you can try something like that:

```
// When you click on your delete icon...
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    // It will select the parent element <li> and remove it.
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

For example:

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="delete">X</button>
    <span>Icon</span>
    <span>Image 1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="delete">X</button>
    <span>Icon</span>
    <span>Image 2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="delete">X</button>
    <span>Icon</span>
    <span>Image 3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: bro how can i remove echo '<input style="width:100%" type="hidden" id="single_img" name="single_img" value="' . $single_img .'" />';                                                                               $single_img = value="432,232,234" so how can remove this single value ??

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: a.h.jony01 is my skype id plz add me

Comment: bro I need help

Comment: Please edit your question correctly with the relevant code, it's not clear what you are asking. I already answered your question in this post.

Comment: bro its my first time so, i am confused.. how to edit in this site